# CSS is not fully applying on a shadow DOM using <slot>

Tags: css, web-component, shadow-dom

I have the following simple component:

Usage:

```
<style>
        my-element {
            --my-bg: green;
            --my-text: red;
        }
</style>

<my-element myStyling>
        <p>Test</p>
</my-element>
```

Component:

```
const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `
<style>
:host([myStyling]), :host([myStyling]) {
    background-color: var(--my-bg);
    color: var(--my-text);
}
</style>
<slot></slot>
      Static
`;
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {

    constructor() {
        super();
        // Attach a shadow root to the element.
        let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
    }
}

window.customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
```

The code outputs the following result:

[image]

Why the `color: green` applies on the static text and the shadow DOM both, while the background color style applies only on the static text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default value for CCS property `color` is **inherit**.

Default style for CSS property `background-color` is **transparent** (won't inherit from its parent element).

Default custom element `display` property is **inline** (= phrasing content) and therefore won't settle background properties to its children.

In your code, the "Test" text is in a `<p>` element, that won't inherit from the `:host` background color, but will be transparent and therefore will display the background color of the main page, which is `white`.

See the live example below for a complete use case.

```js
const template = document.createElement('template')
template.innerHTML = `
  <style>
    :host  {
      background-color: var(--my-bg);
      color: var(--my-text);
    }
  </style>
  <slot></slot>
  <hr>
  Text in Shadow DOM root
  <p>Text in Paragraph in Shadow DOM <span>and child Span</span></p>
  <span>Text in Span in Shadow DOM <p>and child Paragraph</p></span>`
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
        .appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true))
 }
}
window.customElements.define('my-element', MyElement)
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

my-element {
  --my-bg: green;
  --my-text: red;
}
```

```html
<my-element myStyling>
  Text in Light DOM root
  <p>Text in Paragraph in Light DOM  <span>and Child Span</span></p>
  <span>Text in Span in Light DOM <p>and child Paragraph</p></span>
</my-element>
```

If you want the `background-color` to be applied to all the child elements inside the Shadow DOM, you must apply the css rule to the * selector too:

```
:host, * {
   background-color: ...
}
```

If you want the `background-color` to be applied to all the light DOM elements inserted with `<slot>`, you must add a `::slotted(*)` pseudo-element rule:

```
:host, *, ::slotted(*) {
   background-color: ...
}
```

**Alternate approach**

If you want the `background-color` to be applied between the different parts of text, don't forger to define the `display` property as **inline-block** or **block** (= flux content).

As a consequence **all** children will display the root block `background-color`.
Here is the complete `<style>` definition for the Shadow DOM:

```
:host  {
    display: inline-block ;
    color: var(--my-text);
    background-color: var(--my-bg);
}
```